# Declaring a global Request.ServerVariable variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

After many many years of using Classic ASP, I am attempting to delve into the world of ASP.Net using VB. 
I have gotten way to use to being able to declare variables on a page, inlclude that file and use it everywhere. 
I am struggling to declare a global variable. I just need

`Dim TheUser As String = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")`

Then use it on a page as `<%=TheUser%>`
I have tried

    `Module GlobalVars
         Dim TheUser As String = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
    End Module`

But then I get "'Request' is not declared."

If I use `Dim TheUser As String = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")`
within a Page_Load sub, the Request part is fine, but then I cant use it on my .aspx page. I get *'TheUser' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

I apologize in advance as if this an extremely remedial question.

I just dont know where I am suppose to declare it, or maybe you can't declare variables to be used everywhere.

Comment: Just one more quick thing. If I use <%= Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")%> on my aspx page it does work, but I really need to set it as a variable to use everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
Module GlobalVars
     Dim TheUser As String = Httpcontext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to .Net!

I would suggest that you abandon the Classic ASP way of doing things, and delve into more more web architecture and practices.

With that being said, look at [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb) to start.  You will have access to objects that will have the values you are looking to use globally.

Obviously there are many ways to do things, and this is just one.

Comment: Except that I am want to be able to grab more than just the AUTH_USER server variable. That is just one example of the Request.ServerVariables I want to set as a global variable. Plus, I am going to be using the AUTH_USER for more than authentication.